# Calculate the current in mA which will be flowing through the two resistors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Three resistors of 3,4 and 5 ohms are joined in parallel in an electric circuit. If a current of 150mA flows through the resistor of 4 ohms,then calculate the values of the current in mA which will be flowing through the other two resistors.

I could not comprehend the question completely.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part don't you understand? This is what 3 resistors in parallel looks like http://www.electronics-radio.com/articles/basic_concepts/resistance/resistors_in_parallel.gif

Comment: The question asks to calculate the current in two resistors. But there are 4 resistors. Even if we consider that 3 resistors are in parallel and supposedly one of them is in series which makes 2 resistors. We already know that the current flowing through one of them is 150mA why does the question ask us to calculate it again.

Comment: It doesn't mention a resistor in series?

Comment: You only list three resistors.  There is no mention of a resistor in series.  You are asked to calculate the current in the "other two resistors", the $3 \Omega$ and $5 \Omega$ ones.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In a parallel circuit, the voltage across each resistor is the same.  What is the voltage across the $4 \, \Omega$ resistor?
Thus we can calculate the current by finding the total voltage. Being in a parallel combination, voltage will be same for all resistors.

By Ohm's law: $V = IR$